# Parsing a string to get particular values

Tags: java, string, parsing

I'm trying to get the values from a string builder , where I've converted the string builder to string to get values but not helping in fetching particular values.

My String builder output is,

```
SN: 00486  Mode:     1
Temp. 15.4 C
Fat............... 0.0%
SNF............... 0.4%
```

well further replaced with characters like,

```
    String i = stringBuilder.toString();
    i = i.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "");
```

here my output is ,

```
    004861.15.4...............0.0...............0.4
```

I expect my output to get only those values(digits) of Temp ,Fat and SNF ,how can i overcome those dots with my decimal points if I use any loops? please help me out anyone.

Expected Output,

15 (two digits) from Temp , 0.0 from Fat , and 0.4 from SNF.

Comment: can you post expected output here?

Comment: Post the exact output string in the body of the question itself using the edit button.

Comment: You expect to end up with this `String`: "`15 (two digits) from Temp , 0.0 from Fat , and 0.4 from SNF.`"??

Comment: well string or int not a problem i'll convert it anyhow once i get them first sir. @Zepyr

Comment: i think string would be absolutely fine with me.

Comment: check this: https://regex101.com/r/7woAvI/1

Comment: you can use "[.] \d[\d.][\d]*" and replace it with ". " to reach to what you want.

Comment: nope it didnt work @epcpu

Answer (score 0):

try this though it`s an ugly piece of code

```
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder("SN: 00486  Mode:     1\n" +
            "Temp. 15.4 C\n" +
            "Fat............... 0.0%\n" +
            "SNF............... 0.4%");
    String str=sb.toString();

    str=str.replace("%","").replace("\n"," ");

    String[] splt=str.split(" ");

    String fullStr="";

    for (String st: splt ) {

        try {
            Double num=Double.parseDouble(st);
            fullStr+=num.toString()+"\n";

        }catch (Exception ex){

        }

    }

    System.out.println(fullStr);
```

here all the number is separated. and you can separate your desired too.

if you need clarification please ask.

Answer (score 0):

Well I've replaced the code by slight change as

i = i.replaceAll("[^\d]", "");

where i got the results as

00486117000240241040719

which i did altered it later by converting to int [] and got the positions of my values,thanks for your reply everyone.

Answer (score 0):

*it is better to read out the searched values with a pattern*

```
Pattern snpat = Pattern.compile( "(?<info>[^\\d\\:\\.\\x20\r\n]+)(:?[\\.]+)(:?\\x20)?(?<value>[\\d\\.]+)[^\r\n][\r\n]?", Pattern.MULTILINE );
Matcher m = snpat.matcher( str );

String rslt = "";
while( m.find() ) {
  String value = m.group( "value" );
  if( m.group( "info" ).equals( "Temp" ) && value.indexOf( '.' ) >= 0 )  // ignore decimal places
    value = value.substring( 0, value.indexOf( '.' ) );
  rslt = String.join( rslt.isEmpty() ? "" : ", ", rslt, value + " from " + m.group( "info" ) );
}
System.out.println( rslt + '.' );
```

gives:
`15 from Temp, 0.0 from Fat, 0.4 from SNF.`

*if You like a  blank before the comma change the delimiter to* `" , "`